# Why would brand new multimeter not work?

Tags: electrical

Just bought a fresh southwire multimeter from Lowe's.

I feel dumb asking, but why would it not work?

I installed battery and have tried measuring different voltages, but get no readings. It does power on though, just constantly reads zero.

Also, I have everything plugged in correct. Black lead is in the com port and red lead is in the voltage port. Knob is turned to whatever is it I may be measuring, have tried 110V wall outlets and also known working batteries.

Comment: Because it's broken? Even new out of the box products sometimes arrive broken. If you accidentally measured voltage with the meter set to one of the current measuring settings you could have blown a fuse, but otherwise, it sounds like the meter is defective.

Comment: most likely broken

Comment: Does it have "data hold" as a feature? If so is it off?

Comment: Pretty clearly a DOA unit if you ask me -- return time?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often electronic device have a "data hold" featured to freeze the display, make sure that feature is turned off.